# C#: wrap syncronous call to introduce timeout

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a syncronous call:

```
var answer = obj.SyncCall(question);
```

It may execute for indefinitely long, but I would like to limit it's execution time:

```
// throws TimeoutException if not complete in 1000ms
var answer = obj.SyncCall(question, 1000);
```

How to wrap a *sync* call into thread to allow described behaviour?

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410602/how-do-set-a-timeout-for-a-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 4.5:
You can run a Task and wait for it for your defined time:

```
Task.Run(() => { answer = obj.SyncCall(question) }).Wait(1000);
```

Pre .NET 4.5:
You can use the same approach, just using ThreadPool and sync object:

```
ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object o) =>
{
  answer = obj.SyncCall(question);
  evt.Set();
});
evt.WaitOne(1000);
```

Comment: Bound to .NET 4.0, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Is there any precautions needed to read an answer from the outside of closure?

Comment: There is nothing happening after running the thread, so you do not need to worry about closure. After leaving wait operation of sync object, you will have your value assigned in answer variable (you just have to define this variable in parent scope)

Comment: Though this seems to be correct, I would be inclined against writing a task whose action is to mutate a variable. The original code does not say what type `answer` is but let's say that it is `string`. I'd be inclined to instead of making a `Task`, make a `Task<string>`, wait for that task to complete or time out, and then if it completes normally, assign the result of the task to variable `answer`. The task should represent the unit of work being done asynchronously, and the assignment to the variable is not part of that work.